# Best practice to access a Parent Class' method but use Child Class attributes (Python)

Tags: python, oop

I have a number of classes and I want them all the inherit a method from a single parent class. However, the input to this method will be different for each child - coming from the child's class attributes.

```
class Parent:

def __init__(self):

def method(self, a, b):
    return F(a, b) 


class ChildA(Parent):

x = Foo
y = Bar 

def __init__(self, thing):
    self.attribute = thing


class ChildB(Parent)

x = Bar
y = Foo

def __init__(self, thing):
    self.attribute = thing
```

From here I want to be able to call, for example: `ChildAInstance.method(x, y)` or `ChildBInstance.method(x, y)`.

Am I approaching this from the right angle? I would ideally need to keep this as a method and not a standalone function, as the method will need to modify self.attributes in the child class instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, the inheritance in OOP will solve it for you.

The child classes inherits `method` because its defined in `Parent`. When you call it on one of the child classes, it's up to you to pass the parameters you want to make it work.

Look at this example:

```py
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self, x, y):
        print("Hello I'm x: %s" % x)
        print("And I'm y: %s" % y)


class ChildA(Parent):

    x = 'foo'
    y = 'bar'


class ChildB(Parent):

    x = 'bar'
    y = 'foo'
```

If you run:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    childA = ChildA()
    childB = ChildB()
    childA.method(childA.x, childA.y)
    childB.method(childB.x, childB.y)
```

You should get:

```
Hello I'm x: foo
And I'm y: bar
Hello I'm x: bar
And I'm y: foo
```

`method` hasn't changed, but I'm choosing which parameter to pass to it in each case.

Let me know if anything's not clear!